# 里でもコイツに言う事を聞かせられるヤツ grammar

Tags: grammar

とにかくやたら気の強い女でしてね、里でもコイツに言う事を聞かせられるヤツは誰もいないぐらいの跳ねっ返りで

lost the context for this but,

i almost feel like 事を聞かせられる is potential rather than causative passive,

"no one can make her do what is told"

otherwise コイツに with 言う事を聞かせられる as a causitive passive means that コイツ is the one that is making ヤツ do 言う事を聞く, which doesn't really match up with the opening/end of the sentence well.

In any case, how do i interpret 里でも?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this 聞かせられる is causative-potential. But ヤツ is trying to make コイツ (=女) do something, not the other way around. In other words, this に is part of the `AにBをV(さ)せる` construction rather than the `AにV(ら)れる` construction. Here's the breakdown:

- 言う事: what someone says (hereafter translated as "what is told")
- 言う事を聞く: to do what is told
- 言う事を聞**かせる**: to make someone do what is told
- **コイツに**言う事を聞かせる: to make **her** do what is told
- コイツに言う事を聞かせ**られる**: can make her do what is told
- コイツに言う事を聞かせられる**ヤツ**: a person who can make her do what is told
- コイツに言う事を聞かせられるヤツ**は誰もいない**: there is no one who can make her do what is told

In general, when a に-marked word is used with a causative-potential verb, its role can be ambiguous:

> 彼にその小説を書かせられるとは思いません。
>
> 1. I don't think I can make him write the novel. (彼 is the "causee" of the causative verb)
> 2. I don't think he can make the novelist write the novel. (彼 is the subject of the potential verb, and there is an implied causee)

Of course context usually tells which is correct.

This 里 refers to her hometown (typically a small town in a rural area), and 里でも is "even in her hometown".

Comment: 「里」に関しては、この場合本当に小さい集落にしか使わないと思いますし、現代日本の地点を指して実際に使われることはあまりないということも書いておいた方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: @broccoliforest 追記しました。でも、東京に出てきた人が地方の県庁所在地レベルの都市を指して「里に帰る」と言うことも普通にあり得るかな…という気もします。

Comment: 「里帰りする」という意味でですか？それは初めて聞きました。ありがとうございます。